# Changing matching parenthesis color in WinEdt

Tags: color, winedt, text

I'd like to change the highlighting color of the matching parenthesis (and later braces and brackets) in WinEdt v10.2. Here is a snapshot of the highlighted parenthesis in default theme:

[image]

I tried changing the parameter `fscParenthesis` defined in `Colors.ini`, but it did't work.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colors which need to be modified are `sclDelimiterCurrentBk` and `sclDelimiterMatchBk` in `Colors.ini` (inside `COLOR_SCHEME="Default Windows and Text Colors"` unless you are using a Windows HC scheme).

In fact these are colors related to "selections" as you can see in `Selections.ini` (Options Interface -> Highlighting -> Selections):

```
SELECTION_MODE="Current Delimiter (4)"
  TEXT_COLOR="sclDelimiterCurrentText"
  BACKGROUND_COLOR="sclDelimiterCurrentBk"

SELECTION_MODE="Matching Delimiter (5)"
  TEXT_COLOR="sclDelimiterMatchText"
  BACKGROUND_COLOR="sclDelimiterMatchBk"
```

The `BACKGROUND_COLOR` is the property which you want to modify :-)